Is there a self-hosted, real-time collaboration tool for VS Code?
I am looking for a way to collaborate with peers within my company. We would like for our editors (Visual Studio Code) to post changes to peers in real-time. One option we found is Microsoft Live Share. Unfortunately, this solution is not feasible because it requires a GitHub or Microsoft login (which is not allowed due to our security policies as a government contractor).
I would like to find a solution that either a) hosts directly on our work computers or b) can be setup on our Linux servers. And to clarify, we do want to continue using VS Code.
Is there any software that we can use for this?
